# Pass List to Variable in URL String

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use a variable that loops through a list of words to be used in downloading password-protected files from a URL.

**sites.txt:**

```
BOS
HFD
LGA
NYC
PHI
WWD
```

**Powershell Script:**

```
$sites = Get-Content C:\Users\...\sites.txt

$time = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")

$Username = 'hello'
$Password = 'world'
$url = "http://my.website/" + $sites + "/some.csv"

$Path = "D:\...\...\" + $sites + "/some.csv"
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($Username, $Password)
$WebClient.DownloadFile( $url, $path )
```

I am getting "unexpected token" errors so, I'm assuming that I am not using the `$site` variable correctly in the URL string.

Comment: I wonder if it's simply that a combination of slashes and backslashes are used when the $Path variable is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sites = Get-Content C:\Users\...\sites.txt
ForEach ($Site in $sites){
$url = "http://my.website/" + $Site + "/some.csv"
$Path = "D:\...\...\" + $Site + "\some.csv"
$Path
$url
}
```

This will pass your list into individual URL's 
Edited to include change to '$Path' as well.